# Aerospike: Failed to store record. Error: (13L, 'AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_TOO_BIG', 'src/main/client/put.c', 106)

Tags: aerospike

I get the following error while storing the data to aerospike ( client.put ). I have enough space on the drive.

```
Aerospike: Failed to store record. Error: (13L, 'AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_TOO_BIG', 'src/main/client/put.c', 106).
```

Here is my Aerospike server namespace configuration

```
namespace test {
       replication-factor 1
       memory-size 1G
       default-ttl 30d # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.


       storage-engine device {
               file /opt/aerospike/data/test.dat
               filesize 2G
               data-in-memory true # Store data in memory in addition to file.
       }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default namespaces have a [write-block-size](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#write-block-size) of 1 MiB. This is also the maximum configurable size and will limit the max object size the application is able to write to Aerospike.

If you need to go beyond 1 MiB see [Large Data Types](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/ldt.html) as a possible solution.

**UPDATE 2019/09/06**

Since Aerospike 3.16, the write-block-size limit has been increased from 1 MiB to 8 MiB.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but unfortunately, Aerospike has deprecated LDT [(https://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-ldt/](https://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-ldt/)). They now recommend to use [Lists](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html) or Maps, but as stated in their post:

> "the new implementation does not solve the problem of the 1MB Aerospike database row size limit. A future key feature of the product will be an enhanced implementation that transcends the 1MB limit for a number of types"

In other terms, it is still an unsolved problem when storing your data on SSD or HDD. However, you can store larger data on memory namespaces.